# ajax dynamic dorp down population code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using ajax javascript dynamic populate drop down code
it is working on localhost but giving error on server. This is my code:

the error message is below

There was a problem while using XMLHTTP

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// Roshan's Ajax dropdown code with php
// This notice must stay intact for legal use
// Copyright reserved to Roshan Bhattarai - nepaliboy007@yahoo.com
// If you have any problem contact me at http://roshanbh.com.np
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getState(editionid) {      

        var strURL="findstate.php?Edition="+editionid;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readystate == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                     
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);

            req.send(null);
        }       
    }

</script>
```

Comment: but sir on selected event change when i am selecting dropdown its not populating data  or value it showing error. how to resolve this...

Comment: Do you have any console errors???

Comment: yes it displaying foll. error on dialog box

Comment: There was a problem while using XMLHTTP

Comment: That is not a console error. That is an alert from the script. Hit F12, look in the console, look in the network tab. Do some work on your own